Error while building a jar locally in gradle project
We have a legacy repository running on Gradle 2.11. Need to add some local jars as dependency. Here's what my build.gradle file looks like:
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

I'm getting package does not exist error on running ./gradlew build command:
/*/src/main/java/helloWorld/retail/bulkupload/exchanges/directTriggers/PROIndentTrigger.java:10: error: package retail.helloWorld.common.clients.po.internal does not exist
import retail.helloWorld.common.clients.po.internal.POClient;

Verified that the jar file in the libs folder has the path which was not found. Also tried to add dependencies individually but getting the same error:
compile files('libs/common-extensions-1.220.jar')

